# Paid extra vs paid extra cash

Tags: spoken-english

A peron was travelling on a cab. Later (by mistake) a person payed more than he had to pay,so what would be a natural way to express this idea:

> He paid extra cash to the driver.
>
> He paid extra to the driver.

Can "cash" be dropped? And will it sound okay if I add "a little " as well:

> He paid a little extra cash to the driver.
>
> He paid a little extra to the driver.

Comment: If it was a mistake: he overpaid the driver. "Paying extra to the driver" means he tipped, and that is not a mistake.

Comment: And if the cab driver asked for 
more than what was to be given? @WeatherVane

Comment: The driver over-charged him. That might or might not be a mistake.

Comment: Or, he paid the driver too much. Your sentences all mean that he tipped the driver.

Comment: Will "he payed the driver too much" mean tht he "tipped the driver " or "he was over-charged by him"? @WeatherVane

Comment: The second one. Tipping is voluntary, so it isn't "too much" but "extra".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this was in error:

> He **overpaid** the driver
>
> He **paid** the driver **too much**
>
> He **gave too much** to the driver.

or more specifically

> He gave the driver **a twenty** when he meant to only give him **a ten**.

If it was intentional, like as a tip, then:

> He gave the driver **a little extra** (as a tip).
>
> He slipped the driver **an extra five/fiver** (as appreciation).
>
> He told the driver to **keep the change** (as a tip).